# What is the Google Analytics cookie expiration?

Tags: google-analytics, cookie, users

Do you know how long it takes for the Google Analytics cookie to time out before a user is recognized as new again? I believe it is 2 years.  Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what cookie you mean exactly, 2 years would probably be the answer you're looking for based on this source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage

**Additional details**

Google itself lists three main cookies that are set by the analytics script:

- "_ga" with a lifetime of "2 years" that is "Used to distinguish users."
- "_gid" with a lifetime of "24 hours" that is "Used to distinguish users."
- "_ga" with a lifetime of "1 minute" that is "Used to throttle request rate."

Beyond that there are 7 more specific cookies that handle things like distinguishing between users/sessions and setting user level data. Their expiration time is between 10 minutes and 2 years.

Comment: Yes, I  read this information which is how I deduced the 2 years, however, both _ga and _gid both say that they refer to users so it's a little vague.

Comment: There is not alot of info about what _gid is actually used for: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Code/gid-cookie-role-with-new-session/td-p/1144820